# How to make MySQL group by choose one value before another?

Tags: mysql, group-by

```
size   color    in_stock
-----  -----   -----
small   red       0
large   red       1
xlarge  red       1
```

When I'm using `GROUP BY size,color`, the first row with `in_stock` `0` is being chosen over the second row. Is there any way to have `GROUP BY` always give priority for rows with `in_stock` `1`, rather than `in_stock` `0`?

Comment: Append `ORDER BY in_stock DESC` to the end of your statement.

Comment: I already tried that. Unfortunately it's ordering after it groups by, so it's not having any effect.

Comment: please show your complete query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: No

I suspect (because you don't supply your original query) that you are using something like this:

```
SELECT size,color, in_stock
FROM atable
GROUP BY size,color
```

MySQL allows a GROUP BY clause to have just a few non-aggregating columns - BUT it only does so by virtue of a server setting

see: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-handling.html

If you use this "feature" there is no control over what data is chosen in the other non-aggregating columns.

You should NOT use this "feature" of MySQL because if the server settings turn off this extension your queries will no longer work.

You could do something like this instead:

```
SELECT size,color, MIN(case when in_stock = 1 then in_stock else NULL end)
FROM atable
GROUP BY size,color
```

Comment: btw: I'm not sure why you would ignore a stock level of zero

Comment: I didn't want to ignore them so much as not give them priority. The platform I'm working on (Magento) doesn't seem to allow much freedom in  MySQL. I ended up getting the stock of the parent product instead of the child product (The parent will only return 0 if all children are 0). But +1 and thank you for a detailed answer for later! <3

Answer (score 1):

You can use syntax as per below

```
select size, color, in_stock, ....other fields...
from yourtable 
where ...conditions if any....
group by size,color 
order by in_stock desc;
```

Order by always work after group by, so if you want to first order then group. you can use below query-

```
select size, color, in_stock
from 
(
select size, color, in_stock, ....other fields...
from yourtable 
where ...conditions if any....
order by in_stock desc
) as a
group by size,color;
```

Comment: I've tried as you suggested. Unfortunately it didn't seem to affect which ones are grouped, and the order is being applied after the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

If you GROUP BY column(s) and also return a non aggregate column that is not in the GROUP BY clause, then which row that columns value is taken from is not defined. It might be the first one, it might be the last one. It might change depending on storage engine, or anything else.

If you specifically wanted the 2nd one you could do something like this:-

```
SELECT size, color, SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(GROUP_CONCAT(in_stock ORDER BY FIELD(size, 'small', 'large', 'xlarge')), ',', 2), ',', -1)
FROM atable
GROUP BY size,color
```